# How to use create-<breeds>-with between two breed turtle agents?

Tags: networking, netlogo

I've been stuck by this issue for a long time. I have two networks in my model, so I want to create different types of links with different breed turtle agentsets.
Let's name the 1st turtle agentset T1 and the 2nd T2, so what I did is the following:

```
breed [T1s T1]
undirected-link-breed [TL1s TL1]
breed [T2s T2]
undirected-link-breed [TL2s TL2]

;;Got error report
ask T1s [create-TL1s-with other n-of 10 T1s]
```

The last line gave an error reporting that "You cannot use breeded and unbreeded links in the same world". I'm quite confused about what this means.

And then, I changed the last line to:

```
ask T1s [create-links-with other n-of 10 T1s]
```

It worked this time, but if that's the case, how can I define two different types of links, i.e., TL1 and TL2, with different turtle agentsets T1s and T2s?

Can anybody help me out? I really appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That error means that you've created some links that have no breed (probably with `create-link-with`) before creating links with a breed, or vice-versa. If you want to use link breeds, you can never use `create-link-with`, `create-link-to`, or `create-link-from`. You must always use `create-<breed>-with`, `create-<breed>-to`, and `create-<breed>-from`.

So, search your code for instances of `create-link-with`, `create-link-to`, or `create-link-from` and either delete them or change them to `create-<breed>-with`, `create-<breed>-to`, or `create-<breed>-from`. If you're still getting the error, call `clear-all` or `clear-links` to make sure you've removed all unbreeded links.

Comment: Hi @Math, I might be able to help but it looks like you deleted your question.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you so much for your help. Yes, sorry, I had deleted since I found a way to create directed/undirected links (defining breeds undirected/directed edges and using them instead of links-with/to. Thank you for your help